# ESX NFS error "Cannot open volume: /vmfs/volumes/

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I'm trying to add an NFS share to my ESX 5.5 server. When I try to add the share, I get the following error:

Call "HostDatastoreSystem.CreateNasDatastore" for object "ha-datastoresystem" on ESXi "[ESX Server's IP address]" failed.

Operation failed, diagnostics report: Cannot open volume: /vmfs/volumes/07188eae-a88dc069

I'm fairly certain that the VMKernel is setup correctly, because when I vmkping the NFS server using the CLI, I get replies. When I did some googleing, I read that it might be a firewall issue. I went to the Security Profile page under configuration, and found that the NFS Client was not allowed in the firewall. I added it to the allowed outgoing connections and specified "all" as the allowed IP addresses. I then attempted to add the NFS share again, and got the same error. Upon looking at the Security Profile again, the NFS Client was no longer allowed through the firewall.

Comment: What have you entered for the mount properties ("Server" and "Folder")?

Comment: @VFrontDe "server" is the hostname of the nfs server, which is a Windows Small Business Server 2008, and the folder is the name if the share I set up (folder properties --> NFS sharing tab).

Comment: Check this forums thread, it should help: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2461528

Answer (score 1):

Changing to "Allow unmapped user unix access solve this" solves this issue

[image]